# NGINX : How do I serve application via subdirectory?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm working on an app where users can create a subdomain like `<subdomain>.maindomain.com`, and then have it appear under their own domain, for example as `xyz.com` or `pqr.xyz.com`, while maintaining a white-label identity.

Is it possible to configure NGINX so that the content from `<subdomain>.maindomain.com` can be displayed on `xyz.com/pqr`?

Essentially, when someone visits xyz.com/pqr, they would see the content from the subdomain, but the URL remains as xyz.com/pqr.